# How to find out what command was done with my FTP log?

Tags: ftp, logging

My `index.php` files has suddenly been deleted today. I downloaded the FTP log file from the server. I see that an unknown user has accessed my FTP server today. I have the following line in my FTP log, but don't know how to read it:

```
Fri Dec 31 13:25:51 2010 0 ::ffff:[IP HERE] 10079 [FILE NAME] a _ o r [USERNAME] ftp 0 * c
```

What do the following pieces of information mean? **10079** and **a_ o r** and **0 * c** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FTP logs are largely in `xferlog` format. That follows this convention:

```
current-time   transfer-time   remote-host   file-size   filename   transfer-type   special-action-flag   direction   access-mode   username   service-name   authentication-method   authenticated-user-id  completion-status
```

In your case, I believe you are interpreting `10079`, `a_or` and `O*c` as three separate pieces of information. Those pieces of information are actually seven distinct pieces of information

- `10079` is the file size
- `a` is transfer type (`a` stands for an ascii transfer)
- `_` is the special-action-flag (`_` means no action taken)
- `o` is the direction (`o` is for outgoing)
- `r` is for access mode (`r` is for "real" or locally authenticated user)
- `0` is for authentication-method (`0` = none)
- `*` is for authenticated-user-id (`*` means "not available")
- `c` is for completion-status (`c` means "complete" for a complete transfer)

Check out `man xferlog` for more information. Here's [a web based man page for `xferlog`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-0698/6mgftc1sa/index.html).